# Trigger :hover in Google Chrome using JavaScript

Tags: google-chrome, hover, mouseover

I am trying to add the `:hover` pseudo-class to an element using JavaScript.

I do not want to use a simple `.hover` class, because it is clearly redundant, and, I hope, avoidable.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
// creates a new mouseover event
var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
event.initEvent('mouseover', true, false);

// applies this event to my HTML element
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

This thing works perfectly in Firefox if the element is a button.

Trouble is, the `:hover` CSS rule is not applied in Chrome or on a `<div>` element.

A demo is available here:

http://jsfiddle.net/thZ7r/

P.S. Thanks RobW for the answer. I still feel it is a little bit ugly to use `.hover` for a drag-and-drop effect but it seems like it is the only choice left.